# change or add css to theme from plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, css

I want to add/change the CSS of my current theme from my plugin.

I've tried `add_action` and `wp_enqueue_style` and doesn't work

My code:

```
function register_plugin_styles() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'fh-plugin' , plugins_url( 'nf-plugin/includes/f-hide.css' ));

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );
```

Comment: Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add `__FILE__` to your [`plugins_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) function. It may not be calling the right location. It should look like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_238154_register_plugin_styles' );

function wpse_238154_register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fh-plugin' , plugins_url( 'nf-plugin/includes/f-hide.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
```